# JPA avoid sending id when creating the object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to send via json a Question calling my endpoint but he's asking me for id, and I don't know who to do to avoid it, I read about @JsonIgnore, but I don't know if that's the way to do it.

This is my model :

```
   @Entity(name = "question")
   public class Question extends DateAudit {
       @Id
       @Column(name = "question_id")
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_seq")
       @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_seq", allocationSize = 1)
       private Long id;

       @Column(name = "text_question")
       private String textQuestion;

       @Column(name = "answer_description")
       @NotBlank(message = "Answer description")
       private String answer_description;

       @Column(name = "is_exam_question", nullable = false)
       private Boolean is_exam_question;

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
       private Set<Answer> answers;

       @Column(name = "answer_type", nullable = false)
       private String answerType;

       public Question(String text_question, String answer_description, String answerType, Set<Answer> answerSet, Boolean is_exam_question) {
           super();
           this.textQuestion = text_question;
           this.answer_description = answer_description;
           this.answers = answerSet;
           this.answerType = answerType;
           this.is_exam_question = is_exam_question;
       }

       //Getters
   }
```

And this is my endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/create")
       @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
       @ApiOperation(value = "Allows the teacher to create a question and add it to the repository")
       public ResponseEntity<?> createQuestion(@Valid @RequestBody Question questionRequest) {

           if (questionService.existQuestion(questionRequest) != null) {
               //Question already exists
               return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("Question already exist on your repository", false));
           } else {
               questionService.create(
                       questionRequest.getText_question(),
                       questionRequest.getAnswer_description(),
                       questionRequest.getAnswerType(),
                       questionRequest.getAnswers(),
                       questionRequest.getIs_exam_question()
               );

           }
           return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("Question added successfully", true));
       }
```

I generated the swagger and he's asking for those values :

```
    {
     "answerType": "string",
     "answer_description": "string",
     "answers": [
       {
         "answer_to_question": "string",
         "createdAt": "2019-03-01T16:44:05.102Z",
         "id": 0,
         "updatedAt": "2019-03-01T16:44:05.102Z"
       }
     ],
     "createdAt": "2019-03-01T16:44:05.102Z",
     "id": 0,
     "is_exam_question": true,
     "text_question": "string",
     "updatedAt": "2019-03-01T16:44:05.102Z"
   }
```

How do I create a question without adding those ids? But when getting the question I'd like to get the id instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude property from swagger annotate field whit @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)

Comment: With this I'll get the Id when I do a Get and when I do a put I won't add it to the json body?

Comment: @StuartDTO I misunderstood a question, did you tried adding "@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)" on id field?

Comment: Not to swagger, that's a good point thought I didn't know about that, but I want to create a question without adding the Id as a parameter since it's autoincrement one so I don't know the number... and also to assign the answer to the question is not doing well because I don't know how to assign it when it's not created yet, I mean the flow is create the question and the answer at the same time

Comment: Well from REST client just don't pass 'id' field or pass null, if you wanna make Post from swagger you have to exclude 'id' too.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example to how to post a new question from client side? Not creating a client, just how JSON should like? or how do I know the json that it's specting? If the id is autoincrement I can not pass them as a json value

Comment: Hey @Romas maybe you can help my friend out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950130/jpa-add-question-with-answers-assigned-to-that-question